# html rounding with mask="9?9?9?9?9.99"....about 1/4 of the time

Tags: html, angularjs, validation, input-mask

I freelance for a client who says that 1/4 of the time that they input a dollar amount into this textbox style, the value rounds to the dollar floor originally typed in. I can't get any other information regarding this such as browser type and versions. I tried using `type="number"`, but that causes the value currently in the database to not be displayed on the UI (event though the database type is decimal). Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<div class="col-xs-3" >
  <input type="text" ng-model="buyback.buyback" class="form-control"  mask="9?9?9?9?9.99">
</div>
```

Comment: hi Elena, this is an AngularJS question not an Angular question, I'll change the tag, hopefully you'll get some help

Comment: @mediocreCoder, here's a [minimal Plunker setup](http://plnkr.co/edit/LXLjr4?p=preview) with the mask in your snippet. Please provide more information on what the allowed values for this input is. The mask is likely setup incorrectly.